# How to create method to sort by property value (string)?

Tags: sorting, vue.js, cxjs

I'm creating the following list in Vue by iterating through `payeefundingAccountList`.

```
<cx-select id="payee-select" @cxChange="changeSelectedPayee" class="dropdown">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose payment account</option>
  <option
    v-for="(account, index) in payeefundingAccountsList"
    :value="index"
    :key="index"
    :checked="index === paymentAccountSelectedIndex"
  >{{ account.bankName }}...{{account.displayAccountNumber}}({{account.accountType}})</option>
  <option
    v-bind:key="payeefundingAccountsList.length + 1"
    v-bind:value="payeefundingAccountsList.length +1"
  >Add a payment account</option>
</cx-select>
```

I need to sort this list by the property `account.accountType`. This property can have two values: `CHECKING` or `SAVINGS` and I need the items with accountType `CHECKING` to be sorted to the top.

I'm trying to create a method to run the list through before iterating, as such:

```
v-for="(account, index) in sortByAccountType(payeefundingAccountsList)"
```

...but, I'm having some trouble getting any sort of results from the `sortByAccountType` method. I feel like my approach is way off. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be over the moon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property where you can make your sorting before v-for loop start using it. For instance, if your collection "payeefundingAccountsList" is a data property in data, then the computed property would look like this:

```
  computed: {
    sortedList() {
      return this.payeefundingAccountsList.sort(this._compare);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    _compare(a, b) {
      if (a.accountType < b.accountType) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.accountType > b.accountType) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0;
    },
  },
```

And then use this computed property in your v-for:

```
<option
    v-for="(account, index) in sortedList"
/>
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Unexpected side effects in computed property", so it seems I'm unable to manipulate the list in the computed property itself. Is there a workaround for this? I tried implementing _compare() in computed and called it in the methods, but this is also not working

Comment: Yes, in this case eslint complains that the array is mutated and this could cause confusion -> https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.html If you wish you can disable this warning or you can make the sort in the template like this: <option
      v-for="(account, index) in payeefundingAccountsList.sort(_compare)"
      :key="index"
    >
    </option>

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort` modifies the original array, which causes the "side effects" warning. You should clone the original array, and sort that instead.

Answer (score 1):

@Nikolas Yankov is right. But do yourself a favor and import the one function from lodash:[_.sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#sortBy). You can:

```js
import _sortBy from ‚lodash/sortBy‘

export default {
  computed: {
    sortedAccountsList() {
      return _sortBy(this.payeeFundingAccountsList, [‚accountType‘])
    }
  }
}
```